# Adjust inline-flex elements to the screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

In the image below you can see a div (red background) with three divs (green background) inside and each of them with a label (blue background) and a control (input or checkbox) inside.

[image]

In the image you can see how the green divs adjust to the size of the screen and when they reach their minimum size and no longer fit in the line they move down, the problem is (as you can see in the third windows) it looks awful when they are in different lines because of their minimum size attributes, what I want to do is to make them occupy the 100% of the screen when they move down.

I hope I explained correctly.

By the way, I don't want to use plugins, so if there is a way of doing this with only HTML, CSS and Javascript I would be very happy.

Thank you so much by advance.

Here is my code:

```css
.controlRow
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: Red;
}

.controlColumn1-2, .controlColumn1-4, .controlColumnCheckbox
{
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: green;
}

.controlColumn1-2      { width: 50%;    min-width: 300px; }
.controlColumn1-4      { width: 25%;    min-width: 300px; }
.controlColumnCheckbox { width: 230px; }

.controlColumn1-2 label, .controlColumn1-4 label, .controlColumnCheckbox label
{
    margin-right: 5px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.controlColumn1-2 input, .controlColumn1-4 input
{
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.controlColumnCheckbox input
{
    margin-left: 105px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "controlRow">
  <div class = "controlColumn1-4">
    <label id="lblNombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNombre" maxlength="100" />
  </div>
  <div class = "controlColumn1-2">
    <label id="lblDescripcion">Descripcion:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtDescripcion" maxlength="100" />
  </div>
  <div class = "controlColumn1-4">
    <div class = "controlColumnCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id = "checkActivo" checked="checked" />
      <label id="lblActivo">Activo.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use Javascript to perform the calculation of the size of the elements, and set it appropriately.

Comment: But how can I do that? when I should call the function?, what function would it be?

Comment: Isn't this what `flex-grow` and `flex-wrap` are for? (Also `flex-basis` I guess.) [Here is some potentially useful information.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
.controlColumn1-2  { width: 50%; min-width: 300px; }
.controlColumn1-4  { width: 25%; min-width: 300px; }
```

Try this:

```
.controlColumn1-2 {  flex: 2 0 300px; }
.controlColumn1-4 {  flex: 1 0 300px; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/usLhcgze/)

Learn more about the [**`flex`** property at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Also a great reference: [***Common Values of Flex***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)